# How do I specify what info is sent to a webhook from an incoming SMS?

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-twiml

When I specify the webhook to send the contents of an incoming SMS in Twilio, there is no option to determine what information is being sent to that webhook, and I end up getting a whole bunch of information when all I really want is just the body of the message. Is there any way I can specify what is being sent?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot directly modify what is sent. You could proxy the webhook request through some logic like a [Twilio Function](https://www.twilio.com/docs/runtime/functions) which could then send only the key:value pairs you are interested in receiving.